# How do i compare 2 arrays and their values and produce an action based on the comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

This each statement is apart of a larger function which gets a **children** object(array) passed in. The issue im having is that im trying to compare array of values from the children object thats being passed in to a dom element on a page. **In short how do i compare 2 arrays? If the values in passed array (Children) are not on the page or found in the dom then add the values to the DOM. If the values are already in the DOM then do nothing.**

```
$.each(children,function(){
            for (var i in children){
                var the_child = children[i];
                var the_child_check = $("#" + the_child.id, self.container);

          }

          if(self.container.children.length >=0){

              self.container.tabs('add', '#' + the_child.id, the_child.label);

          }else{

              self.container.tabs('remove', '#' + the_child.id);
});
```

Once i understand how to implement this logic, then i should be able to incorporate this into its proper place into the function.

```
<div id="tabcontainer">
                       <ul id="tab1">
                           <li>tab 1</li>
                       </ul>
                        <ul id="tab2">
                           <li>tab 1</li>
                       </ul>

</div>
```

This is a basic example of how the html is constructed. each tab is dynamically generated based on the passed in array object (**children**)

Comment: How does your html look like ?

Comment: I don't think we need the html at all. I'm just trying to figure out what are these two arrays of yours. You only seem to care about the children based on the description of what you want to get done.

Comment: Where is your `else` closing bracket? Is it missing in your original code?

Comment: the arrays are (ie. [chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4] = children array) DOM array (ie. [chart1, chart2]) the DOM may have charts are being exposed so we don't want to add the chart again to the DOM if a call is made by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

This assumes you have set `self` somewhere prior.

```
// i gets index, val receives the item of the current iteration
$.each(children, function(i, val) {
    // code
    if (self.container.find(val)) {
       // item exists in dom
    } else {
       // item does not exist in dom
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nuc! This really gave me a boost to where i need to be. The idea about passing the variables i and val was on target! Didn't know those variable were exposed through each.. thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray

Here is jquery inArray,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var arr = [ 4, "Pete", 8, "John" ];

    $("span:eq(0)").text(jQuery.inArray("John", arr));
    $("span:eq(1)").text(jQuery.inArray(4, arr));
    $("span:eq(2)").text(jQuery.inArray("David", arr));

  });
```

Comment: Thanks chad for your effort. I honestly didnt know about the jQuery inArray function. Review the docs.. looks like something i'll have to add to my toolkit.